# BMI & BMR calculator

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a method that takes a user's height, weight, and age, and returns their BMI and BMR.

I think I've done this fine.

However, the last thing I need to do is add some validation to make sure the user has put in some sensible numbers. The constraints being applied to the input are:

```
50 [cm] ≤ height ≤ 220 [cm]
10 [kg] ≤ weight ≤ 250 [kg]
18 [years] ≤ age ≤ 70 [years]
```

To do this, I've tried using if statements

```cs
if (getHight >= 220 && getHight <= 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
else if (getAge >= 70 && getAge <= 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
else if (getWeight >= 250 && getWeight <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
```

However, regardless of what I ender, nothing shows up in the console by way of validation errors. It just outputs my BMI and BMR.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Today is the day you learn to use the debugger.  Put a stop break on a line of code and run your program and when it stops, look at the values and then go line by line by pressing F8 to see what your program is doing.

Comment: Just think about what the first line of code says in english - if height is greater than or equal to 220 AND less than equal to 50. Can a number be greater than 220 AND less than 50 at the same time? It is one OR the other.

Comment: Also note, if you say that a valid weight must be greater than or equal to 50, or less than or equal to 220 - then 50 & 220 are valid weights, so your if statements should check for less than 50 & greater than 220.

Comment: Another improvement might be to tell the user which particular entry is invalid - ie. height/weight/age - rather than use the same error message for each. If you insist on using the same message, then all checks could be combined into a single if statement.

Comment: It's spelled `height` btw

Comment: Also, not sure if you made these constraints yourself or not but a 50cm minimum height is insanely small...

Comment: @ScottishTapWater thank you for enlightening me about the typo. The constraint is not made by me, but yea i can only agree that its extremely small haha

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you are using AND instead of OR.

You cannot both be taller than 220cm and shorter than 50cm.

Use OR operators instead of AND:

```
if (getHight > 220 || getHight < 50)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
else if (getAge > 70 || getAge < 18)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
else if (getWeight > 250 || getWeight < 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unfortunately, your input is incorrect, please try again");
}
```

Also as @PaulF mentioned, you should not be using `<=` and `>=` since the valid range of values is inclusive. Since your logic is the inverse (invalid values), you should drop the `=` and just use `<` and `>`.

Comment: Note you should be using > & < the heights/weights/ages - as OP originally stated <=/>= the particular values as being valid.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, you should be using `||` instead of `&&` when doing the comparisons and you should be using `<` and `>` since the boundary values are acceptable. You might spend some time reading up on the [Boolean logical operators - AND, OR, NOT, XOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators) so they all make sense, because they're very common and used in just about every program you'll write.

---

I just wanted to add another possible solution in case you're doing a lot of these types of comparisons, which is to write an extension method for them. This way you only have to write it once, which reduces the chance of error.

Below I have an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) that tests if a number is between a minimum and maximum value (along with an option to specify if those boundary values as valid). Note that I assumed you're testing with an `int` type, but you can change the  type easily by changing the `this int value` to `this double value` or `this float value`, or whatever numeric type you're using:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsBetween(this int value, int min, int max, 
        bool inclusive = true)
    {
        return inclusive ?
            min <= value && value <= max:
            min < value && value < max;
    }
}
```

Now if you include that class in your project, we can use this method to test if the value is ***not*** between our accepted values by using the `!` not operator. Also note that I changed the `else if` to separate `if` statements. This way, if there's more than one error, they all get reported at the same time and the user can correct them all at once. I also changed the error message so the user actually knows what's wrong and how to fix it:

```
// In your program class, not in the Extensions class above

if (!getHeight.IsBetween(50, 220))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Height must be an integer between 50 and 220");
}

if (!getAge.IsBetween(18, 70))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Age must be an integer between 18 and 70");
}

if (!getWeight.IsBetween(10, 250))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Weight must be an integer between 10 and 250");
}
```